# Python Pandas better way to find the date when amount is greater than a goal

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out when particular users first reach a set goal. As a simplified version I have 2 datasets (1 of donations and 1 of fundraisers)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
Donations = pd.DataFrame({
           "id": pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),
           "amount": pd.Series([10, 15, 10, 15, 10, 20, 70, 20,20,30]),
           "solicitor": pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1,1,2]), 
           "day": ([1,2,1,2,2,3,2,4,5,5]), 
           })
Fundraisers = pd.DataFrame({
           "id": pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]),
           })
```

so assuming the goal is 30 I want to find the first day each fundraiser raised at least $30.
I accomplished this by using a groupby and for loop

```
def test(group, amount):
    group = group.sort("day")
    myamount = 0
    date = np.NaN
    for i in group.index:
        myamount = myamount + group.loc[i, "amount"]
        if (myamount >= amount):
            date = group.loc[i, "day"]
            break
    return date
Fundraisers =  Fundraisers.set_index(['id'])
Fundraisers["first day"] = Donations.groupby(["solicitor"]).apply(lambda x: test(x, 30))
Fundraisers = Fundraisers.reset_index()
```

I just get the feeling there is a better way to go about this than using a for loop to go through each donation. So wondering if there is a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I suppose that the id of Fundraisers is unique, therefore I suggest you to use the id as index. In your example I would do something as:

```
Fundraisers = pd.DataFrame(index= pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Then I suggest you a code like:

```
Donations.sort("day",inplace=True)
cumulative_amount = Donations.groupby('solicitor').amount.cumsum()
Fundraisers['first day'] = Donations[cumulative_amount>=30].groupby('solicitor').min().day
```

What about it?

Comment: Cheers. Only thing to change would be adding Donations = Donations.sort("day") before the cumulative_amount code.